# What is Failed requests ratio in Soap UI

Tags: load, soapui

Please see my image, the err is: 146 and the rat is: 200. I understand that there are 146 errors of my assertion, Could you please explain for me the value "200" rat, what and why it is ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rat column is the percentage of assertion errors to the number of requests. If you have 73 requests and 146 errors, it looks like you're getting multiple errors per request so your rat is 200%.